# AutoSize and Size property in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, height, autosize, groupbox

There is GroupBox on the Form with below properties:

```
AutoSize = true;
AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink;
```

It seems, if you add Control into this GroupBox, the GroupBox's height will be:

`Control.Top + Control.Height + 20;`

Is there any way to decrease this number ---> `20`?

Comment: turn autosize off and do it yourself?

Comment: You can use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345967/groupbox-with-a-flowlayout-panel-inside-and-autosize-true-shrinks-like-it-is-e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AutoSize = true` means that the control will start calling the `GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)` method.

You can subclass `GroupBox` and override the `GetPreferredSize` method.

Comment: Hi, How to override it?

Comment: Same as overriding any other method. Write a class extends `GroupBox` and then start typing `override ... `